# Make 1 javascript/function affect several classes at once - how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am using the following code on my webpage, in order to format certain numbers (with the ".pricetag" class), as i need to show them as currencies (comma separated at thousands) on my front end:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.fn.digits = function(text){
        $(this).text(text.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + '€' );
    };
    var tempText = $.trim($(".pricetag").text());
    tempText = tempText.substr(0, parseInt(tempText.length) );
    $(".pricetag").digits(tempText);
});
```

So far so good - code works fine, and does what i need it to.

My problem is that i have more classes than just the ".pricetag" class, for which i want to use the function. So right now i have copy pasted the code, and just changed the target class (".pricetag_2" etc.).

How do i tell one version of the javascript/code, to affect several classes (both ".pricetag" and ".pricetag_2") in stead of having to copy paste the same piece of code, let's say 10 times, to target 10 different classes.

It's a bit overkill to have so much code, as the function is exactly the same every time. In CSS it's pretty easy, as you can affect several classes at once, by comma seperating them within a piece of code, but how do i do it in javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: `$(".pricetag, .pricetag_2")` ?

Comment: the `$` function takes a CSS selector, so it works the same way "in javascript" as it does in CSS. In other words, you can do `$(".class1, .class2, .class3")` and so on. You probably want to make a variable (perhaps even an array) of all your classes, for ease of maintenance.

Comment: jQuery selectors "*extends*" CSS ones, so you'll be able to separate your classes by commas, as abney317 showed you.

Comment: Ok thanks - i tried that already, but it gives me an output of all classes at once, in all fields.

What i mean is this - on the frontend:

Pricetag 1: 1,200,000€ 125,000€

Pricetag 2: 1,200,000€ 125,000€

In stead of this - the way it should be:

Pricetag 1: 1,200,000€

Pricetag 2: 125,000€

Answer (score 0):

If all your classes begin with `.pricetag` you might try the [attribute-starts-with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

```
$("[class^='pricetag']").digits(tempText);
```

Comment: Thank you Ben. I just added this to my code. Not it gives me an output of all classes at once, in every single field. What i mean is this - on the frontend: Pricetag 1: 1,200,000€ 125,000€ Pricetag 2: 1,200,000€ 125,000€ In stead of this - the way it should be: Pricetag 1: 1,200,000€ Pricetag 2: 125,000€. Any idea what to change in the code?

Comment: Maybe try `var pricetags = $("[class^='pricetag']")` -- that should give you an array of jQuery elements. Then, `for(var i = 0; i < pricetags.length; i++) { $(pricetags[i]).digits(tempText); }`. Does that work?